# Get ChromeType from within current web part

Tags: javascript

How do I retrieve the ChromeType for the current running web part from within itself (something like "this.Chrome.ChromeType")?

If the ChromeType is something other than "None" I want to add some extra lines of HTML to the output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[WebPart.ChromeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.chrometype%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)